# Book about character transported to a realm where his written words become spells

Tags: story-identification, magic

I remember reading a book, probably 15-20 years ago now, but I cannot remember the name.  It is about a character (some type of English professor/student?) who through some fashion is transported to another realm, where he learns that his written words become spells - and the "Spirit of Entropy" is with him and he can command it with his words as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for the name of a book where a physicist gets transported to a medieval world](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87948/looking-for-the-name-of-a-book-where-a-physicist-gets-transported-to-a-medieval)

Comment: Clearly not the stories asked about, but might be worth noting as there are some similarities that might cause somebody searching for them to end up here: the *Spellsinger* series by Alan Dean Foster has a main character who is a student (of Law, not English) who is transported to another world where his words (sung, not written) cause magical effects.  The last couple of books of the series were also published in about the right time frame (although the bulk are a little older).

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like [*The Oathbound Wizard*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/363876.The_Oathbound_Wizard):

> Matt Mantrell 20s is Lord High Wizard in world where **poems are spells**, and oaths unbreakable. After 3 years wait to marry love Queen Alisande, he angrily swears to take Ibile from evil Gordorgrosso. New pals - surly dracogriff Narlh, courtly cyclops Fadecourt, damsel Yverne, well-wist spirits, wee Puck, Robin Hood - join old - Sir Guy, dragon Stegoman, demon Max.

And a [quote](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8leUAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT221&lpg=PT221&dq=the+oathbound+wizard%22+%22spirit+of+entropy%22&source=bl&ots=LcCySasP_x&sig=T-Wa3jIB8g0jSTSrGsjPIgbUZVg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAGoVChMIi8fq44HKyAIVSTkUCh1iGQt1#v=onepage&q=the%20oathbound%20wizard%22%20%22spirit%20of%20entropy%22&f=false) (emphasis mine):

> Narlh frowned at him. "Who's Max?"
>
> "Maxwell's Demon! The one I told you about, **the Spirit of Entropy**! He controls the organization of matter and energy!"

Comment: Bah.  Beat me to it by seconds.  ([I was busy detailing the other books in the series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wizard_in_Rhyme)) Ah, well +1 :)

Comment: @K-H-W Fastest gun in the west ;-)

Comment: If it is, we have a definite dupe.

Comment: @SeanDuggan, do you mean the partial duplicate (same series) as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87948/looking-for-the-name-of-a-book-where-a-physicist-gets-transported-to-a-medieval ?

Comment: @Otis: Yes. That would be the one.

Answer (score 0):

Inkheart trilogy were everything the character reads becomes true but it takes an eye for an eye

Comment: Can you expand on why you think this is what the OP is looking for? Quotes from the books, plot summaries, *anything*?